# What are the msvcp140_1.dll and msvcp140_2.dll files in the Microsoft C runtime?

Tags: c, msvcrt

I am trying to import a C library into a Visual Studio project. The library ships with the following files:

```
msvcp140.dll
msvcp140_1.dll
msvcp140_2.dll
```

I understand that these are Microsoft C runtime DLL files. But I'd like to know more about the purpose of those files. I'd like to know what binaries I need and what consequence including them has.

What is the purpose of the `msvcp140_1.dll` and `msvcp140_2.dll` files?

Comment: C++, not C.  Five years ago Microsoft released msvcp140.dll and promised to keep it binary-compatible with future releases.  That was a very welcome and popular promise, but the C++ committee did not stop adding features.  msvcp140_1 takes care of operator new(size_t, align_val_t), msvcp140_2 covers the added special math functions in cmath.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those files are actually the C++ Standard Library implementation (see the `p` in their name). From the `C++ Standard Library` section on [CRT Library Features | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019):

> When you build a release version of your project, one of the basic C
>   run-time libraries (libcmt.lib, msvcmrt.lib, msvcrt.lib) is linked by
>   default, depending on the compiler option you choose (multithreaded,
>   DLL, /clr). If you include one of the [C++ Standard Library header
>   files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/cpp-standard-library-header-files?view=vs-2019) in your code, a C++ Standard Library will be linked in
>   automatically by Visual C++ at compile time. For example:
>
> ```
> #include <ios>
> ```
>
> For binary compatibility, more than one DLL file may be specified by a
>   single import library. Version updates may introduce dot libraries,
>   separate DLLs that introduce new library functionality. For example,
>   Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6 introduced msvcp140_1.dll to support
>   additional standard library functionality without breaking the ABI
>   supported by msvcp140.dll. The msvcprt.lib import library included in
>   the toolset for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6 supports both DLLs,
>   and the vcredist for this version installs both DLLs. Once shipped, a
>   dot library has a fixed ABI, and will never have a dependency on a
>   later dot library.

Since Microsoft's C++ Standard Library is open-source you can easily look up what those additional features are, e.g. [`stl/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/9a0a17e66c4137a8211e61f57bb368d21782e615/stl/CMakeLists.txt) even describes the files:

```
# msvcp140_1.dll (the memory_resource satellite)
```

and

```
# msvcp140_2.dll (the special math satellite)
```

However [the source filenames](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/9a0a17e66c4137a8211e61f57bb368d21782e615/stl/CMakeLists.txt#L382-L388) are already descriptive on their own.